# Undefined reference to cv::imread linking error

Tags: c++, opencv, linker-errors, caffe, undefined-reference

I'm trying to install a modified version of caffe as part of the installation of this library: https://github.com/wasidennis/ObjectFlow/tree/master/caffe-cedn-dev
I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and am using a cmake install as listed on the caffe website.

I've installed matlab & have the mex file in the path.

after `cmake ..` I do a `make all` and get this error:

```
Linking CXX executable caffe
../lib/libcaffe.a(io.cpp.o): In function `caffe::ReadImageToDatum(std::string const&, int, int, int, bool, caffe::Datum*)':
io.cpp:(.text+0x67d): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'

../lib/libcaffe.a(window_data_layer.cpp.o): In function `caffe::WindowDataLayer<float>::InternalThreadEntry()':
window_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe15WindowDataLayerIfE19InternalThreadEntryEv[_ZN5caffe15WindowDataLayerIfE19InternalThreadEntryEv]+0x44b): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'

../lib/libcaffe.a(window_data_layer.cpp.o): In function `caffe::WindowDataLayer<double>::InternalThreadEntry()':
window_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe15WindowDataLayerIdE19InternalThreadEntryEv[_ZN5caffe15WindowDataLayerIdE19InternalThreadEntryEv]+0x446): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Following https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1276 I looked at the output of `pkg-config --cvflags opencv` which is `-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include`

This is the same location as the headers of my OpenCV installation are installed. (I'm not sure of the causal relationship on that.) Both OpenCV 3.1 and 2.4 go to those files - I tried installing both and to switch between them I just move the `opencv` and `opencv2` header folders to a tmp folder while I use the other opencv. I think this might be the source of the error, as I don't know how to tell which version of OpenCV my program is using for sure.

More specifically I have done is:

I added `opencv_imgcodecs` to the Makefile

installed opencv via apt-get

uninstalled opencv via apt-get remove

installed a version of opencv that I don't remember the version

installed 3.1 & 2.4 from src & switched out the header folders as stated above.

Deleted a version of opencv src & header folders that I didn't know how to see what version it was.

From when I started checking, python import cv2 went from version 3.1 to now 3.2-dev.

Comment: what exactly is `cmake ..`, and what does the variable `OpenCV_LIBS` in CMakeCache.txt say?

Comment: I could only do 2 links, but I was following 
 this http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html, where I make a build folder and then "cmake .." inside of that.

In the CMakeCache.txt inside of the build folder there is not an OpenCV_LIBS variable. There was these though:
//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.
OpenCV_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/share/OpenCV


//Details about finding OpenCV
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_OpenCV:INTERNAL=[/usr/local][cfound components:  core highgui imgproc ][v3.2.0()]

Comment: You can rename the opencv folders to something else to test which one is being used. Just see for which one renaming it changes things.